# UI-Router give cannot GET error on page refresh

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am building an angular site and using UI-Router, if I click a link to go to a route it works fine but whenever I refresh the page, or if I type the url in manually I get 'Cannot GET /find-a-vendor.  I have this in my routes file:

```
$stateProvider
   .state('home', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
    })
    .state('find', {
       url: '/find-a-vendor',
       templateUrl: 'views/find.html'
    })
```

I also have `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` in my routes file as well. and in my index I have `<base href="/">` in the header, is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Is it a full stack app? Or just a front-end app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had this issue before and found [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions) article that helped me tremendously. You need to do some server side rewrites.

Comment: Thank you, I found what I needed to change and fixed it

Comment: would have been better if you added the specific part that you used to solve this problem